# Allowing SFTP user to specific root directory only

Tags: directory, root

I want to allow a SFTP limited user to access and change scripts in specific root directory called `/root/scripts` with SSH access disabled. I am having a hard time finding any solutions.

The main server is executing these scripts so directory must stay in root folder.

Also setting user `-s` to `bin/nologin` or `bin/false` disables somehow sftp access too, nothing happens when tries to login. **EDIT:** using shell /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server works ideal.

**Current situation:**

in
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

using

> ```
> Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
> Match User specops
> ChrootDirectory /root/scripts
> AllowTCPForwarding no
> X11Forwarding no
>
> ForceCommand internal-sftp
> ```

Also this is executed:

> ```
> chown specops "/root/scripts"
> usermod -d "/root/scripts" specops
> ```

Now connecting with specops I find myself in /.. directory without any directories listed

Running Debian 6   E.G user specops

Comment: And what have you done so far? I guess you've created an sftp cage right? How did you do that, did you pointed the user to the directory you mention?

Comment: Updated with current detailed situation

Comment: specops directory should be /root, not scripts. The base dir where the users start should be owned by root and only have acess to the subdirectories inside there on the other hand, `usermod` command is OK since the user base directory should be that. Check the next link https://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze

Comment: Changed to /root. service ssh restarted. /root is chmoded 744, /scripts to 777. Still I find myself in /.. directory with specops without nothing inside. Some rights missing..? passwd: specops:x:1001:1001::/root:/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Comment: Fixed rights. At least 755 were needed. Now it's working like planned. Thank you for right direction.